# NSXPCConnection or XPCKit

Tags: cocoa, xpc

There are two choices (or at least I know two) for implementing XPC client and service for Mac. NSXPCConnection which is introduced in 10.8 and [XPCKit](https://github.com/amazingsyco/XPCKit). What should I use to implement helper app that resides in menu bar and uses XPC to read data from the main app.

The main difference I see is that `XPCKit` will work in 10.7 Lion while `NSXPCConnection` is available only in 10.8 Mountain Lion. What else should I take into consideration when choosing between them. I'd be grateful for the responses from the developers who used both.

P.S. My app still works in 10.7, however from my previous experience it's not a problem to require the latest version of OS X in 2-3 months after release.

Comment: I'm not sure you can use XPC for rpc between an app and helper app.  I think XPC can only be used to communicate with XPC services that are part of a single app.

Comment: Richard Stahl. You can use XPC for IPC between an application and its helper. By using the application-groups entitlements available since 10.7.4 and adding the helper to login items using SMLoginItemSetEnabled(), a mach service will be automatically registered for the helper app named with its bundle id, and then the main app can do IPC with it through this service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided to use NSXPCConnection.

- It is provided by Apple, so, less chances to have problems with updates.
- Since the release of Mountain Lion and NSXPCConnection it seems that XPCKit is not supported any more.
- I've tried both and for me personally NSXPCConnection seems to be a better solution